# (C++) While loop not working once I introduce more than one variable

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a program that accepts certain user input and if the user does not enter a valid input the program will loop and ask again. When I am only using one variable to the program behaves as I intend. However, once I introduce more than one variable to the while loop, it seems to no longer recognize the input as true. Thus, just repeating the loop even when correct input is given. Seeing as how there are six true inputs (B, S, D, b, s ,d) I am a little worried that I am unable to even get two to work. I am new to C++ and any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
//Asking user to input a package
      cout << "Which package are you shopping for? (Enter B, S, D): ";
      cin >> choice;

      while((choice != 'B') || (choice != 'b'))
      {
         cout << "Enter only B, S, or D." << endl;
         cout << "Which package are you shopping for? (Enter B, S, D): ";
         cin >> choice;
      }
```

Comment: The condition to your while loop is always true. Perhaps you meant to use && instead.

Comment: Can you have a value that is that is at the same time B and b?

Comment: You can do onething. Make an while(true) loop and ask for input. Then use a simple if condition to check if the input is correct then break it.

Comment: Read much [more about C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and a good [C++ programming book](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html) and [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Consider compiling your C++ code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` (all warnings and debug info) then use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). Provide some [mre] in your next question please

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true)
{
   cout << "Enter only B, S, or D." << endl;
   cout << "Which package are you shopping for? (Enter B, S, D): ";
   cin >> choice;
   if(choice == 'B' || choice=='S' || choice=='D')
    {
       break;
    }
   else
    {
      court << "Enter valid input" << endl;
    }
}
```

Try this. I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using `&&` instead of `||` in your `while` statement. Also to clean things up a bit, I like to use the 'toupper' function in `<cstring>` in this situation.

`#include <cstring>`

```
char choice, upper;

cout << "Which package are you shopping for? (Enter B, S, D): ";
cin >> choice;

upper = toupper(choice);
while (upper != 'B' && upper != 'S' && upper != 'D') {
    cout << "Enter only B, S, or D." << endl;
    cout << "Which package are you shopping for? (Enter B, S, D): ";
    cin >> choice;
    upper = toupper(choice); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the `choice=='B'` then the first condition will be 0 and the second will be 1. You are ORing 0 and 1 so we will enter the loop again.

Suppose also the `choice=='b'` then the first condition will be 1 and the second will be 0. You are ORing 1 and 0 so we will enter the loop again.

Suppose the `choice` equals any later different than `'b'` or `'B'` then the first condition will be 1 and the second will be 1. You are ORing 1 and 1 so we will enter the loop again.

The right solution is

```
 while((choice != 'B') && (choice != 'b'))
```